# How to remove duplicate timestamp in R with a column having both Date-Time and Zone

Tags: r, date, time, zone

I have a data frame in R with several columns. I am copy pasting one of the columns below. The column type is integer in the data frame and the +00.00 represents UTC time.

```
D-T-Z                               

06/04/2018 16:30:01 +00:00              
06/05/2018 20:15:00 +00:00              
06/05/2018 12:45:34 +00:00              
06/05/2018 20:15:00 +00:00
```

When I use library(doBy) and the command Mach1[firstobs(Mach1[, 16]), ]. I get the result below

```
  D-T-Z
06/04/2018 16:30:01 +00:00              
06/05/2018 20:15:00 +00:00              
06/05/2018 12:45:34 +00:00
```

I want to filter the data frame and get single records for distinct dates. Because the time is different, it is returning two records for 06/05/2018, whereas I only want one record returned. Does not matter what time is returned. Is there any other way to make this happen?

What if the data frame has two columns?

```
date                                               Hour
```

1  2018-06-04                                          325.2
2  2018-06-05                                          329.5
3  2018-06-06                                          329.7
4  2018-06-07                                          329.9
5  2018-06-08                                          333.2
6  2018-06-13                                          356.0
7  2018-06-14                                          364.8
8  2018-06-15                                          372.6
9  2018-06-15                                           381.9
10 2018-06-21                                          383.3
11 2018-06-22                                          394.5

Comment: if your time column is already in date format, then you can do `data[!duplicated(as.Date(data$\`D-T-Z\`)),]` if not, You can convert it to time  `data[!duplicated(strptime(data$\`D-T-Z\`,"%m/%d/%Y")),]`

Comment: How is it related with Time Zone?

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and show the output of `dput(head(Mach1[, 16])`. This well help to better reproduce the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lubridate`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data_frame(date = c("06/04/2018", "06/05/2018", "06/05/2018", "06/05/2018"), time = c("16:30:01", "20:15:00", "12:45:34", "20:15:00"), zone = c("+00:00", "+00:00", "+00:00", "+00:00")) -> x

# all data in one column
x %>% select(date) %>% unique()

# data in separate columns using lubridate
apply(x, 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse = " ")) %>% dmy_hms -> y
y %>% as_date() %>% data_frame() %>% unique()
```

output 1:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  date      
  <chr>     
1 06/04/2018
2 06/05/2018
```

output 2:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  .         
  <date>    
1 2018-04-06
2 2018-05-06
```

Comment: @Paul- Thanks for the reply. Your solution works only if there is a dataframe with only the date column. Suppose I have a data frame as shown in the modified question above. How I can I eliminate the duplicate dates? Please let me know.